# Why is it not possible to initialize a final variable in a catch block?

Tags: java

### Case Study 1

```java
    final String someString = "Hello World";
    try {
      someString = "Hello";
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
      someString = "World";
    }
```

If we compile this code, we get two errors:

> Cannot assign a value to final variable 'someString' // Line 3

> Cannot assign a value to final variable 'someString' // Line 5

This, I understand. It's a final variable, you've already assigned a reference to it, and you cannot change it anymore. Nice.

### Case Study 2

```java
    final String someString;
    try {
      someString = "Hello";
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
      someString = "World";
    }
```

If we compile this code, we get only one error:

> Variable 'someString' might already have been assigned to // Line 5

This, I don't understand. We are allowed to initialize in the try block. Still, if something fails, even before the actual initialization is done, we're not allowed to initialize the final variable in the catch block.

Why is that so? I was expecting we could initialize the variable in the catch block as the `try` block failed anyways.

Comment: [A "why" question like this is inherently unanswerable.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/5133585) Please edit to clarify what you mean by "why". For example, what behaviour did you expect the code to produce instead?

Comment: Once assigned, `final` variables cannot be modified

Comment: @Sweeper Elaborated my Question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr:** When we reach the catch-block the try-block has failed, but we don't know *where* it failed. It might have failed before, during or after assigning to the variable. Therefore the compiler can't allow a possible re-assignment to a `final` variable.

**Long answer:** A `final` variable has to be assigned *exactly* once before it can be read. Not less (i.e. never assigned), not more (i.e. assigned twice). Exactly once.

For this reason the following code is trivially wrong:

```
final String someString;
someString = "Hello";
someString = "World";
```

The second assignment will result in a compile time error, since `someString` was definitely already assigned.

Now let's look at this code:

```
final String someString;
try {
  callSomeMethod();
  someString = "Hello";
  callSomeOtherMethod();
} catch (Exception e) {
  someString = "World";
}
```

Now we've run into a problem: the compiler can't know when the exception that causes the catch-block to be executed is thrown: it could be thrown in `callSomeMethod()` or in `callSomeOtherMethod()` (or through some miraculous internal problem even when trying to assign the constant).

So the compiler simply doesn't know if `someString` will have been already been assigned to inside the catch-block or not (and both options would theoretically be possible at runtime!). If the variable had been assigned, then the assignment has to be a compile time error. If it wasn't it would be fine. But since static analysis can't tell you which one it is, the compiler has to mark the whole assignment as an error.

Now in theory in some corner cases the compiler *could theoretically* know that a variable was definitely assigned in the `try` block, even when an exception occurs. Specifically if it's the first action and it can prove that the assignment action can not throw an exception. But if that's the case, then the programmer can just trivially move that assignment *out* of the try-block and avoid the whole problem. That's *probably* why no such rule exists in the JLS.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, a final variable is a variable that is initialized once and cannot be reassigned. The reason why it is not possible to initialize a final variable in a catch block is that the catch block is only executed when an exception is thrown, and the Java compiler cannot guarantee that the initialization will always happen.